# Using CAShapeLayer fill color issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cashapelayer

I want to draw a circle with text inside.Unable to display text.Any help?

Below image is ref. for expected behaviour.

[image: expected behaviour]

Below is the code for reference:

```
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 40, 40, 40)];
lblTitle.text = @"Me";
lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLight" size:10.0] ;

lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[view addSubview:lblTitle];

CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circleLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)].CGPath;
circleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:56.0/255.0 green:212.0/255.0 blue:203.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.lineWidth = 1;
[lblTitle.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

Comment: You can also try by setting cornerRadius of `UILabel`

Comment: You're adding the shape layer on top of the label, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setting cornerRadius of `UILabel` as @Sujay said:

```
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 80, 40, 40)];
lblTitle.text = @"Me";
lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

lblTitle.layer.borderWidth = 1;
lblTitle.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
lblTitle.layer.cornerRadius = lblTitle.bounds.size.height / 2;
lblTitle.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:56.0/255.0 green:212.0/255.0 blue:203.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];

lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLight" size:10.0] ;

lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:lblTitle];
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible using CAShapeLayer?

Comment: Thank you, @Bannings for giving credit, you could have upvote my comment as well.

Comment: @Sujay Is it possible using CAShapeLayer?

Comment: @user2931321 You can using CATextLayer

Comment: @user2931321, Yes it is possible but need to check because I havn't done it practically.